# Block a user with acl

Tags: 12.04, acl

How can I block one user and grant access to another user using an ACL?

I tried `setfacl -Rdm u:maria: /home/elena` but I think this is wrong.

`maria` is one user and `elena` is another user.

Answer (score 0):

If `elena` and `maria` are two different users, with two different `user-ids`, you can execute the following command and allow read/write access to `/home/elana` only to`elana` (and `root`):

```
sudo chmod 700 /home/elana
```

Explain:

> - sudo - execute command as `root`
> - chmod 700 /home/elana- change mode of the directory to read/write/execute by owner only

Now, other users (including `maria`) won't be able to access `/home/elana` (unless they can get `root` access - e.g. using `sudo`)

Comment: It worked great :) But can I do the same procedure with an access list?